# Is there any better way to parse two lists simultaneously?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to guess the perfect combination of two numbers within two huge lists.

```
for x in list_a:
    for y in list_b:
        if round((x * 0.24 + y * 0.13), 2) == value:
            print('success')
```

This tho is taking a lot of time because my lists' len surpasses 600. My first thought is to split the huge list into smaller lists and check the result . For example, If the equation of x and y <= value - 4 to move to the next list's set until x and y == value.

1)How can I split my lists into smaller clusters? 
2)How to effectively change sets?
3)Is there a way to avoid nested for loops?

Comment: Are you okay with `numpy` solutions? And can you give example lists?

Comment: Yeap, I already use np.arange to create my lists. List_A could be [425.01, 424.99 .....,395.02] and List_B [ 3,65, 3,66, ... 4,36]. 
Note that these values are not static. And I need to remake these lists for another set of values. That's why I need to develop an algorithm to parse faster and smarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE (question clarified):**

No need to guess, since you can solve exactly (up to numerics):

```
M = np.array([[1, 1], [0.24, 0.13]])
high_taxed, low_taxed = np.linalg.solve(M, [Start_Value, Tax])
```

Update ends.

You can use the following trick to get O(n+m log n+m) runtime.

1. scale the lists a and b by the factors 0.24 and 0.13
2. replace b with v-b
3. observe that a_i + b_j is close to v precisely when a_i is close to (v-b)_j
4. with that in mind combine a and v-b, sort, and take the diff between all neighboring elements that are not from the same subset
5. find the smallest element in the diff. this corresponds to the best match

.

```
import numpy as np

def closest_match(a, b, v, fa=24, fb=13, fv=100):
    ab = np.concatenate([fa*a, fv*v - fb*b])
    idx = ab.argsort(kind='stable')
    ina = idx<len(a)
    swtch, = np.where(ina[1:]^ina[:-1])
    mm = np.diff(ab[idx])[swtch]
    abidx = swtch[np.argmin(np.abs(mm))]
    aidx, bidx = sorted(idx[abidx:abidx+2])
    bidx -= len(a)
    return aidx, bidx
```

Example:

```
a = np.arange(-10, 10000, 7)
b = np.arange(20, 4000, 3)
v = 99
closest_match(a, b, v)
#(1, 249)
a[1]*24 + b[249]*13
#9899
v*100
#9900

# best match is one off
# validate using brute force

np.abs(np.add.outer(a*24, b*13)-v*100).min()
#1

# yep, one is as good as it gets
```

Timings compared to brute force:

```
timeit(lambda: np.unravel_index(np.abs(np.add.outer(a*24, b*13)-v*100).argmin(), (len(a), len(b))), number=1000)
#17.82432043197332
timeit(lambda: closest_match(a, b, v), number=1000)
#0.11731306000729091
```

Speedup is more than 100x.

Comment: Very interesting thought. I have trouble understanding it. I get an error because I use float. I try to run closest_match(401.28 , 3.65, 0.24, 0.13, 99.23) . 401.28 is the first element of my list_A. 3.65 is the first element of my list_B. 0.24 is to calculate 24% tax. 0.13 is to calculate 13% tax.99.23 is the combination of the two values. Also, I need to store these two values. Brute force gives me the result 395.33 from the first list and 33.44 from my second list

Comment: @Magotte The first two arguments (`a` and `b`) must be 1D arrays. You can extract the values using the indices returned, see the example.

Comment: It's working correctly, `a*0.24 + b*0.13=Tax` but `a+b != Start_Value`.
My data :
`Start_value = 428.77`
`End_value = 528.00`
`Tax = 99.23`
`closest_match prints (388.65 , 45.8)` which is correct with Tax but incorrect with `Start_Value = a + b`. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @Magotte ? Sorry, I don't follow. What is `Start_Value`? I can't see it mentioned in your question. What exactly is the constraint? Please explain.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have three columns `Start_Value`, `Tax`, `End_Value`. `Start_Value` is the untaxed value, `End_Value` is the sum of the `Start_Value + Tax`. Most of the times I have a mixed VAT of 24% and 13% which are not mentioned in the invoice. So I tried to guess those values through brute force. Is there any way to add a condition to your function? So I can have `a+b = End_Value and a*0.24 + b*0.13 = Tax and Start_Value + Tax = End_Value`

Comment: @Magotte See updated post. I put `a+b = Start_Value` assuming that the tax rate is applied to the untaxed value. Let me know if that is wrong so I can fix it if necessary.

Comment: Can I use 4 parameters instead of two? for example a*0.24 + b*0.13 + c*0.06 + d * 0.0 = end result and solve them with linear algebra?

Comment: @Magotte The rule of thumb is you need as many equations as parameters. So I'm afraid that is a no.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure which optimal condition you are trying to find but if you want to reproduce the calculation above without two for loops I might help. Try calculating all values in one numpy array:

`arr = np.around(np.outer(0.24 * np.array(list_A), 0.13 * np.array(list_B)),2)`

It will return a matrix which stores all values you are calculating in your for loops and you can get a Boolean matrix indicating which pairs of A and B fulfill your condition by

```
boolian_arr = arr == value
```

(This solution does not include any fancy search algorithm, but just an alternative to the two slow for loops using numpy.)

Comment: Is this calculating the elements in series? For example, List_A[0] element with List_B[0] element ? My Solution could be List_A[345] element and  List_B[65] element.

Comment: Considering two lists of length n and m, you would get a nxm-matrix with all the pairs. So yes the mentioned solution would also be part of it

Comment: Instead of `boolian_arr = arr == value` use `idx_pairs = np.argwhere(arr ==  value)` and you should get a list of all indices of list_A and list_B which fulfill your condition. Next just use list_A[idx_1] and list_B[idx_2] to get the values

Comment: Sadly I get wrong combinations I believe it's due to float values in my lists

Comment: Hmmm, was the True False matrix already incorrect ? If not, you could double check which idx to use for which list. As far as I can see, the two numpy lines should have the same effect as the two for loops in terms of float value calculation

Comment: Well, maybe I need to reshape my conditions.